# EarPods pause/play when moving

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I have encountered a strange behavior twice already, with two separate EarPods headsets. After about a year of using the headset, the cable near the jack gets slightly worn out and it causes really irritating behavior - when bent, it **pauses/plays** song while listening to music. It also hangs up a call just by bending.

Anybody encountered this behavior? Is there something I can do or the only thing is to just throw it away and buy a new one...again?

**EDIT:**

1. Just to clarify - it is definitely not shake to change feature. I tried it with the phone being stationary and just fiddling with the cable.
2. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54985/iphone-pauses-or-plays-songs-when-the-headphone-plug-moves?rq=1) question doesn't provide any solution or answer to my question - "what can I do".

Answer (score 2):

Misuse is dramatically shortening the life of your cables.

Flexing the cable near the plug will eventually break down the cable shielding, causing electrical shorts, with random results.

- First, buy a new headset.
- Second, either learn to treat it gently, or invest in some [Sugru](https://sugru.com/great-for/gadgets-and-tech) which is great for protecting the point where a cable meets the plug.

[image]