# How does macOS detect and choose my wired headphones?

Tags: macos, headphones, microphone, music.app

I have my old-good wired headphones with a mic connected to my mac.
Usually, they lie on the table near my mac.

Sometimes some magic happens when I pick them up, I noticed two kinds of magic:

- I'm on the team call (Webex), listening on the internal speakers, then picking up phones - sound magically switches to phones
- no calls, just working... picking up phones - music.app starts, sometimes it unpauses playing music

Sometimes it happens together - music.app appears during the call and starts playing music, which is pretty weird and annoying

My headphones are not smart and have no sensors, they are as stupid as a microphone and two ears connected to the 3.5 jack

How does it happen?
Does mac os listen to me?
Can I configure this behavior somehow?

Comment: Are you sure WebEx isn’t playing the sound to both speakers? Also, a photo of the tip lets us know if there’s a TRRS and button that sends a [signal electrically - especially if jiggled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/216965/5472) or [there is a short.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120293/5472)

Comment: webex definitely plays into a single output at a time, and there is no TRRS

Comment: as for jiggling cable, I never noticed any issues with cable, but will look at this way